# Which is pin 2 on a Harwin Datamate connector?

Tags: connector, datasheet

The datasheet for [M80-6651042](http://www.harwin.com/include/downloads/drawings/M80-665.PDF) Harwin Datamate connector shows us which pin is pin 1.

[image: Harwin Datamate M80]

But which is pin 2? Is it the one to the left, or the one below? Is there a standard direction that pin numbering always goes in for dial row connectors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By far, *most* connectors of this type put the odd-numbered pins on one side and the even-numbered pins on the other, so the answer would be that pin 2 is below pin 1 in this drawing. The reason for this is that this type of connector is often used in conjuction with ribbon cable, and this makes the numbering in the cable sequential.

However, I have seen rare exceptions to this, where pins 1 to N/2 went down one side, and the rest down the other. If you can see the board silkscreen, see if there are any clues indicating whether this might be the case.

If you are designing a new board with this connector, of course, the final answer is entirely up to you.

Comment: Also, given that this connector is available in several pin counts/lengths, it is highly likely that pin 2 is below pin 1 -- ordering them the other way would mean that the assignment of the pin under pin 1 would be a function of the total number of pins in the connector.

Answer (score 2):

It appears there is not "IDC" numbering for this series. If you refer to the following documents you will see the pins numbers run sequentially along the edge:

https://cdn.harwin.com/pdfs/C005XX_M80_and_M83_Datamate_Series_Connectors.pdf

https://cdn.harwin.com/pdfs/Harwin_Catalog_Issue_60_Datamate_L-Tek_pages_17-34.pdf